# How to Animate a custom NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

I'm having some troubles animating a custom NSWindow.

Here's my init method:

```
- (CustomWindow *)initWithView:(NSView *)view
{
    if ((self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect
                                 styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask 
                                   backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                                     defer:NO])) {

        [[self contentView] addSubview:view];

        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor darkGrayColor]];
        [self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
        [self setExcludedFromWindowsMenu:YES];
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setHasShadow:YES];
        [self setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I call `[self setFrame:originalFrame display:NO animate:YES];` there is a delay that corresponds to the animation duration, but the animation itself doesn't occur.

I think this is because I'm using a borderless window?

Comment: Any progress with this? I have the same problem.

Comment: My problem was that I was creating the animation in a background thread (by mistake).

Comment: I think I had the same issue and I could solve it by removing any autolayout constraints that constrain the window size before calling `- setFrame:display:animate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this: `[self setFrame:originalFrame display:YES animate:YES];`

Comment: That didn't help. At this point I'm starting to think it's something else interfering with my code. I'll build a sample project just to make sure.

Comment: How about this: `[[self animator] setFrame:originalFrame display:YES];`

Comment: That's doing something, though now what I'd expect. I'm going to accept your answer for now and make sure everything is ok.

Comment: Your window should animate like 'System Preferences' window does. Check the `originalFrame` and compare it with "current frame". Probably theres something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Guess your window is resized, but view you add to content view, don't. If you have only one view, then instead of:

```
[[self contentView] addSubview:view];
```

use:

```
[self setContentView:view];
```

Comment: Hi Andriy, thanks for the answer but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Did you try to change your call to: `[self setFrame:originalFrame display:YES animate:YES];`?